# Can't get a simple RewriteRule in .htaccess to work in local WAMP

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I've enabled mod_rewrite, restarted all services, still not taking affect. Here's what I have in .htaccess:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule .* localhost/phpinfo.php

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all rewrite rules in general do not affect the host part of the URL (unless you specify predefined names like `REQUEST_URI` etc.) just the path part (an [excellent article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/) explaining the bits and bytes of URL rewriting.) That said your rules should at least look something like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+) /phpinfo.php [L]
```

Furthermore is your `AllowOverride` directive for that particular vhost (or folder) configured to allow `.htaccess` files at all? If not `.htaccess` files will be completely ignored. In order for mod_rewrite to work it needs to be set at least to `FileInfo Options`.

```
AllowOverride FileInfo Options
```

Comment: Thanks. AllowOverride directive was the problem.